# How do I calculate the effect of increasing CPU speed when T(N) = O(2^n)?

Tags: big-o

I have been presented with the following scenario: algorithm A is O(2^n). I can either pick a CPU 10x faster, or pick algorithm B which is O(n^2). Obviously I would pick algorithm B, but I need to justify this mathematically, not just through reasoning.

I have been told that algorithm B allows me to solve a problem that is (2^n / n^2) times bigger. This I understand. So far so good.

But it goes on to say that the faster CPU allows me to solve a problem (n + log 10) times bigger (approx. n + 3).

How do they get (n + log 10) from (2^n / 10)?

Answer (score 1):

The time it takes to solve the problem is the amount of work, divided by CPU speed, which could be expressed as (2^n)/speed for the first algorithm. Multiply the speed by 10, and it's (2^n)/(10*speed). What they really mean by "allows you to solve a problem X bigger" is "allows you to solve that bigger problem IN THE SAME AMOUNT OF TIME."

So, (2^n)/speed = (2^(n + biggerness) ) / (10 * speed) . Solve algebraically for biggerness, and you end up with biggerness = speed log 10 .